# Javascript function how to wait some time before a function executes which takes the final value if there is a certain change during that time

Tags: javascript, function, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, vonage

So basically i have a firebase cloud onWrite function which when executed calls the client to alert him to open his dashboard. i am using the nexmo api. anyway, what i am trying to do so to make the function wait for sometime before it executes because the value may change , if it changes (do not call the client) if no change call him
like this:-

```
// When new order is placed call the function  
// Wait for 10 min if there is any change
(if there is no change to that value) {
 call();
} else {
 if the value changed during that time stop the function
 return;
}
```

i have tried setTimeout() but it executes upon the initial value i want it to execute upon the final value after 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I did it , i made a counter in the client side and after 10 min it resets to 0 using setTimeout(), and if the counter is zero and value is the still same , call client();
that way the first time its added to database no call will be made because the counter is not 0.
on my client-side i did this

```
// update counter to 0 after 15 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
 firebase
  .database()
  .ref('the place where you want to update')
  .update({ counter: 0 })
}, 15000);
```

and in my cloud function

```
if (counter === 0 && state === 'CALL') {
  call();
} else {
  return;
}
```

that way the api will call the client if he left pending orders for over the set amount of time.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. Did you consider including the actual working code in your answer? That makes your answer more useful for future visitors, and makes it more likely it'll get upvoted.